# How can you search by country and return the title and id matching those countries?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to do a sorter in where you can search by country and then if it matches it should return the title and id matching those countries.

```
static async getMoviesByCountry(countries) {
    /**
    Ticket: Projection

    Write a query that matches movies with the countries in the "countries"
    list, but only returns the title and _id of each movie.

    Remember that in MongoDB, the $in operator can be used with a list to
    match one or more values of a specific field.
    */

    let cursor
    try {
      // TODO Ticket: Projection
      // Find movies matching the "countries" list, but only return the title
      // and _id. Do not put a limit in your own implementation, the limit
      // here is only included to avoid sending 46000 documents down the
      // wire.

      cursor = await movies.find({
          country: {$in: [countries]}})
          .then(
            movies.findOne({_id:_id, title: title})
          )
          .limit(1)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Unable to issue find command, ${e}`)
      return []
    }

    return cursor.toArray()
  }
```

I've tried doing this in where you search the country by the ones that are included in countries and then find movies by id and title. But this is not working.

```
  cursor = await movies.find({
          country: {$in: [countries]}})
          .then(
            movies.findOne({_id:_id, title: title})
          )
          .limit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> ```
> let collection countries = [
>         {
>           "countryId": 1,
>           "Countryname": "India",
>           "movieId": 11,
>           
>         },
>         {
>           "countryId": 2,
>           "Countryname": "India",
>           "movieId": 13,
>           
>         },
>         {
>           "countryId": 3,
>           "Countryname": "China",
>           "movieId": 12,
>           
>         },
>         {
>           "countryId": 4,
>           "Countryname": "Japan",
>           "movieId": 14,
>           
>         },
>         
>       ]
> let movies=  [
>         {
>           "MovieId": 11,
>           "title": "Movie 11",
>           "description": "Description 11",
>           
>         },
>         {
>           "MovieId": 12,
>           "title": "Movie 12",
>           "description": "Description 12",
>           
>         },
>         {
>           "MovieId": 13,
>           "title": "Movie 13",
>           "description": "Description 13",
>           
>         },
>         {
>           "MovieId": 14,
>           "title": "Movie 14",
>           "description": "Description 14",
>           
>         },
>         {
>           "MovieId": 15,
>           "title": "Movie 15",
>           "description": "Description 15",
>           
>         },
>         
>       ]
>     }
> ```

Query

```
db.countries.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "movies",
      "localField": "movieId",
      "foreignField": "MovieId",
      "as": "data"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$data",
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      Countryname: {
        "$in": [
          "India",
          "China"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Expected Output

```
[
  {
    "Countryname": "India",
    "MovieId": 11,
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "countryId": 1,
    "description": "Description 11",
    "movieId": 11,
    "title": "Movie 11"
  },
  {
    "Countryname": "India",
    "MovieId": 13,
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "countryId": 2,
    "description": "Description 13",
    "movieId": 13,
    "title": "Movie 13"
  },
  {
    "Countryname": "China",
    "MovieId": 12,
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "countryId": 3,
    "description": "Description 12",
    "movieId": 12,
    "title": "Movie 12"
  }
]
```

Check this [Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/05Ut76_QIeF)